# Avoiding repeat upload of same file on remote host with ftp

Tags: ftp

I have ubuntu 14 headless server and I have data continuously updating on it. I wish to take back up every 15 mins to remote host. I don't have much access to remote host and I just have to drop files on it. I have successfully established FTP bash script which runs every 15 mins. Now I dont same files to get uploaded on remote host. Once file is upload,I don't want same file to upload on remote host. I have written bash script for FTP upload but I don't know what to do with this repetition upload.

there is something

file /path/to/upload -maxdepth 1 -mtime 0.04 > path/to/filelist.txt

But this is of no use and my files repeatedly keeps uploading same files again and again over 15 mins (I have set up cronjob after 15 mins)

Please help me,I am a Linux newbie,little illustration will be useful.

Comment: Don't you mean `_find_ /path/to/upload -maxdepth 1 -mtime 0.04 > path/to/filelist.txt`?

Comment: It's not clear to me, if you are uploading to the Linux server or from the Linux server. If "to", what is your local system?

Comment: I am uploading from Linux server to FTP accessible host (I don't know the nature of machine which is remote and I can't access folders or any such thing,I am suppose to just upload using FTP to my clients FTP accessible host and that's it)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use `rsync` instead of ftp. It was built for this and is much more efficient.

If you have to use ftp, `find` should work for this. Try this format:

```
find /path/to/upload -maxdepth 1 -cmin -15
```

where `-15` means less than 15 minutes ago. `+15` would mean older than, and `15` exactly 15 minutes ago.

Alternatively, you can use a reference file or timestamp (which is supported on newer `find`:

```
find /path/to/upload -maxdepth 1 -newerct $(date -Iseconds -d '15 minutes ago')
```

where `-newerct` is a form of `-newerXY`, using the status change time of the reference (`c`) where the reference is a plain timestring (`t`) instead of a referenced file, and is provided by
`date -Iseconds -d '15 minutes ago'`.

---

You might want to be careful with taking backups *too* often, depending on your use-case; or you could overwrite good backups with bad data before you noticed there was something bad with it.
Or add multiple incremental backups to the full backup, so you have the option to roll back to different points in time.

Comment: I get this as output error - "find: I cannot figure out how to interpret `2019-08-31T00:38:45-0400' as a date or time" (without double quotes)

Comment: This is my script#!/bin/sh
DIR="/path/to/upload/
USER="******"
PASS="******"
SERVER="ftp.server.ip"
DIR1="/path/to/save/TXT/filelist.txt"                                         
cd $DIR
#find $DIR -maxdepth 2 -mmin -30 > $DIR1
sleep 5
#FILE=`ls -t *.mkv| head -1`
FILE="*"

ftp -inv $SERVER  <<EOF
user $USER $PASS
put $FILE
quit                                                                               
EOF

Comment: @Merlincool, your time-string works here, using `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0.225`. Try with some date format variations then: `find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds -d '15 minutes ago')"`,  maybe drop the timezone: `find . -maxdepth 1 -newermt "$(date -d '15 minutes ago' '+%F %T')"`.

Comment: Thank you very much I am truly sorry to understand this syntax. My GNU IS 2.2.6 on Ubuntu 14, so which will be correct time syntax 

I want to order my Ubuntu folder to check every 15 mins if any file was newly added to folder, and if it has then please upload via FTP session and also while checking please make sure you don't re-upload the already uploaded file on remote server.

If my syntax is wrong,I would like to know the exact correct syntax that will help me.

Comment: @Merlincool, I don't know which syntax your version of `find` supports, you'll have to check the manual pages yourself, or test around with the date strings I provided. `man date` explains how they are formatted.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me where I can learn how to read the output of this manual. I don't use Linux so much so I don't understand what that string means and how to interpret

Comment: @Merlincool, I've edited the post, this version should work with your `find`. I've changed it to use `ctime` which is probably more useful than `mtime` here. But you can decide on either.